# Finding parrots population

Tags: logic

To determine the number of parrots in a sparse population, an ecologist captures 30 parrots and puts rings around their necks and releases them. After a week he captures 40 parrots and finds that 8 of them have rings on their necks. What approximately is the parrot population?

> The options are
>   1. 70,            2. 150,
>   3. 160,           4. 100.

I can not find any such solution for this in my mind. Can you please help me.

Comment: You have asked several questions here and gotten answers. If the answers helped, you should accept and upvote them.

Comment: I do that @EthanBolker...

Comment: Upvoted, perhaps, since someone has upvoted some answers, but not accepted (the check mark) - only the proposer can do that.

Comment: actually I don't know all the systems in this site.

Comment: @EthanBolker Thanks man for suggesting me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: What fraction of the parrots in his recaptured sample have rings? Well that's $8/40 = 20\%$.

Assume the same fraction of parrots in the wild have rings.

You know $30$ parrots in the wild have rings. $30$ is $20\%$ of what?

Comment: Can you please explain more. I'm not getting the point about fraction

Comment: @mathiu_lady See my edits.